# Configuring Blackberry 5.0 and 6.0 component packs

Tags: blackberry

How to configure Blackberry 5.0 and 6.0 component packs to eclipse 3.4 version.I searched in google for hours but no use..What is the process to configure for 6.0 version...can anyone give any reference sites to download component packs.Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used Eclipse 3.5 version to configure blackberry 5.0 and 6.0 versions...

Comment: With 3.5 version of eclipse Galileo I just add the url in the  http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java in Help>Install New Software window and able to configure the required versions.